# How much should I inflate my tires?

Tags: maintenance, tire

I just purchased a new bicycle pump with a pressure gauge and after checking my tyres, inflated them to the top end of interval printed on the tyres (4.5-6.5 bar).

I'm wondering when the tyres should be in the lower range of the interval, and when the higher end is appropriate. Is it a question of weight? Type of terrain I'm going to ride?

The tyres in question are [Schwalbe Kojaks](http://www.schwalbetires.com/kojak), mounted on a light urban hybrid bike.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What pressure should I run my Mountain Bike tires at?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-pressure-should-i-run-my-mountain-bike-tires-at)

Comment: Duplicate of this [question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-pressure-should-i-run-my-mountain-bike-tires-at), vote to close.

Comment: ...unless there's something specific about Kojaks? (I have a pair, and except for the higher pressure rating, there's not much that general inflation advice won't cover.)

Comment: Disagree that it's a duplicate -- the other question was about trail riding, this is about urban riding.  Plus there's the question of what the minimum rating is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is 10-15% lower than the posted maximum for normal road riding. Higher if you're carrying a load or are a larger rider, lower if you're a lighter rider. There's an article in Bicycle Quarterly that's a pretty good guide on tire pressure for road riding depending on weight and width of tire.

http://www.vintagebicyclepress.com/images/TireDrop.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am a large rider and I was advised (and seen) that I need to keep my tires to the max before each ride.  If I do a long ride - over 2 hours - I have to make sure to check and inflate accordingly.  I ride 700cc road tires and with my weight a tire that starts to slack gets a "pinch flat".  Basically the tube pinches inside the tire.  If you are a very light rider, you can get away with a little less.

If you are riding a bike with "knobbie" tires like a mountain bike, you can get away with less too.

Answer (score 3):

A higher pressure will be faster and 'harder' (less suspension); a lower pressure will be slower (more rolling resistance) and smoother (it'll ooze over cracks and bumps).

I was told that the 'max pressure' is just a guideline and that in practice you can go a little higher. I think my tires say 85 psi maximum, and I inflate them to 95 (not because I'm especially heavy but because I'd prefer to go faster with less effort than smoother).